# double & long double : are they same on my computer?

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point, numerical-methods

This is ANSI C code:

```
   float        x = 3.14159264351134890172;
   double       y = 3.14159264351134890172;
   long double  z = 3.14159264351134890172;

   printf("%f\n",x);
   printf("%f\n",y);
   printf("%f\n",z);
   printf("%.20f\n",x);
   printf("%.20f\n",y);
   printf("%.20f\n",z);
```

Output of this code is:

```
3.141593
3.141593
3.141593
3.14159274101257324219
3.14159264351134881466
3.14159264351134881466
```

See last output line. I have read that `long double` gives accuracy of 19 digits after decimal points. But here I get 15 digits accuracy after decimal point. So there is no difference between `double` and `long double` in my computer. I am using linux kernel `2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64` with CentOS. 
My C compiler is `gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) (GCC)`

Why is this so ? If it depends on computer hardware/architecture, how do I purchase my linux machine in which long double is more precise than double ?
Does it depend on my C compiler also ? If yes, how do I choose my C compiler ?

For `float` value range is `1.2E-38 to 3.4E+38`. I do not understand this. From above example we see we can not store correctly a fractional decimal number such as 3.1415926 in a `float` variable. My machine will store correctly only 3.141592 in that `float` variable. So I have lost last 7th digit which is 6 here. Then why do we say `float` range is 1.2*10^-38 ?

Isn't it that We can not store upto 10^-38 but we can store upto 10^-6 for a `float` variable in C ?

Comment: That's expected on x64. Why do you feel that double will not suffice. Judging by your comments though you don't understand how floating point works at all. You have to put that right before you continue. You need to learn that values are stored as mantissa and exponent.

Comment: You're overthinking it too much. Chances are if you are fighting for `long double` precision, you should be using a different approach instead. Also print `long double` with `"%.20Lf"`.

Comment: Note that you should format `z` with `%Lf` (though you'll get away with it if `sizeof(double) == sizeof(long double)`).

Comment: To check if double and long double has same precision, check the sizeof(double) and sizeof(long double). If sizes are equal, then both represent same precision. This is similar to the case that both int and long int takes 4 bytes where as long long int is 8 bytes and has higher range.

Comment: @prashanthns: equal sizeof does not imply equal precision or range. An implementation can choose to use a wider format for double to e.g. align them better, but do faster operations on them than `long double`. There is only one way: compare the macros provided.

Comment: @Olaf while I agree with your statement, I wonder how often does this occur?

Comment: @DeiDei alternatives approaches not using `long double` when one needs `long double` precision are quite cumbersome, much more complex than simply using `long double`.

Comment: @KamiKaze It doesn't matter how often something might occur. This is StackOverflow, where we never miss an oppo for nit-picking. ;)

Comment: @KamiKaze: More often than not - counting different architectures. Still most C platforms use 16  bit `int` or 32 bit CPUs. Wrt sizes of `int` and `long`, there is a well known counter example: POSIX64 (e.g. Linux), which is I32LP64.

Answer (score 5):

First, you should print `long double` values with `%Lf`.

Second, if you want your `long double` variable to contain a value that cannot be represented as a `double`, you should not initialize it with a `double` constant. `3.14159264351134890172` has type `double` and if your compiler defines `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` to 0 or 1, using `long double  z = 3.14159264351134890172;` sets `z` to a `double` value even if the type `long double` could represent that constant more closely on your platform. Instead, the line should read:

```
long double  z = 3.14159264351134890172L;
```

The short answer to your questions after “For float value range is 1.2E-38 to 3.4E+38 …” is that floating-point formats on your machine are in base 2, and that the representable values are not the same in these formats as if they were represented in base 10. The type `float` on your platform provides exactly 24 **binary** digits of precision. The type `double` provides 53, and you should be able to expect `long double` to provide 64. The long answer is too long for the StackOverflow format, but you might start by reading http://floating-point-gui.de .

Answer (score 1):

Values exist to help answer OP's investigation and can be directly printed to discern how alike `double` and `long double`.  They *could* be exactly the same.

To find the precision of various floating point type, print `***_MANT_DIG`

> number of base-`FLT_RADIX` digits in the floating-point significand, `p`
>     C11§5.2.4.2.2 11

```
#include <float.h>
printf("FLT_RADIX         %d\n", FLT_RADIX);  // Almost always 2
printf("DBL_MANT_DIG      %d\n", DBL_MANT_DIG);
printf("LDBL_MANT_DIG     %d\n", LDBL_MANT_DIG);
```

To find how many decimal digits to print that matches the FP exact value, use `***_DIG`  (Round trips "text-FP-text" as expected)

```
printf("DBL_DIG           %d\n", DBL_DIG);
printf("LDBL_DIG          %d\n", LDBL_DIG);
```

To find how many decimal digits to print that the FP exact value maybe effected, use `***_DECIMAL_DIG` (Round trips "FP-text-FP" as expected)

```
printf("DBL_DECIMAL_DIG   %d\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG);
printf("LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG  %d\n", LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG);

double d = 3;
long double ld = 3;
printf("(double) 1/3      %.*e %.*e\n", DBL_DIG - 1, 1 / d,
    DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, 1 / d);
printf("(long double) 1/3 %.*Le %.*Le\n", LDBL_DIG - 1, 1 / ld,
    LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, 1 / ld);
```

Example output

```
FLT_RADIX         2
DBL_MANT_DIG      53
LDBL_MANT_DIG     64
DBL_DIG           15
LDBL_DIG          18
DBL_DECIMAL_DIG   17
LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG  21
(double) 1/3      3.33333333333333e-01 3.3333333333333331e-01
(long double) 1/3 3.33333333333333333e-01 3.33333333333333333342e-01
```

---

Notes:
For range issues, print `***_MAX, ***_MIN`.
Be sure to use an `L` in the print specifier for `long double`.